# React script takes a very long time to render the server side JSON array from node js

Tags: javascript, jquery, node.js, postgresql, reactjs

I am new to react js. I am trying to populate two tables using the server side data from node js. The data is very huge(about 60-100k json objects in an array). The react js script takes a very long time to render the data in the table. The browser hangs and asks for the script to either stop or continue. I am using postgres as db to fetch data from node server. The code snippets are

Node js - report.js

```js
client.query("SELECT change_data->'api' AS api, change_data->'cts' AS cts from changes WHERE gerrit_id = $1", [gerritId] , function(err, result) {
    if (err) {
      log.e(err);
      res.send({status: 'DB error' + err, data: []});
    } else if (result.rows.length == 1) {
      res.send({status: 'ok', data: result.rows[0]});
    } else {
      res.send({status: 'Api data not found', data: []});
    }
  });
```

React Component

```js
var apiTable = React.createClass({displayName: 'apiTable',

  getInitialState: function() {
    return {
      data: []
    };
  },

  componentDidMount: function() {
    $.ajax({
      url: 'report/api?id=' + this.props.id,
      dataType: 'json',
      method: 'GET' ,
      success: function(res) {
        this.setState({data: res.data});
      }.bind(this),
      error: function(xhr, status, err) {
        React.unmountComponentAtNode(document.getElementById('alert'));
        React.renderComponent(React.DOM.span({className: "alert alert-danger"}, "Error"), document.getElementById('alert')); 
        console.error('Search error', err.toString());
      },
      complete: function(data){
        React.unmountComponentAtNode(document.getElementById('alert'));
      }
    });
  },

  render: function() {
    var apis = this.state.data.api || [];
    var ctsTests = this.state.data.cts || [];

    var apiRows = apis.map(function(apiName) {
      return (React.DOM.tr(null, React.DOM.td(null, apiName.api), React.DOM.td(null, apiName.pathWeight)));
    });
    var ctsRows = ctsTests.map(function(test) {
      return (React.DOM.tr(null, React.DOM.td(null, test.cts), React.DOM.td(null, test.pathWeight)));
    });

    return (
      React.DOM.div(null, 
        React.DOM.div({className: "table-container"}, 
          React.DOM.table({className: "table table-bordered table-hover"}, 
            React.DOM.thead(null, 
                React.DOM.tr(null, 
                    React.DOM.th(null, "CTS test cases"), React.DOM.th(null, "Path Weight")
                ), 
                
                  ctsTests.length === 0 ?
                    React.DOM.tr(null, React.DOM.td({className: "info-row"}, "No CTS test cases found"))
                  : ctsRows
                
            )
          )
        ), 
        React.DOM.div({className: "table-container"}, 
          React.DOM.table({className: "table table-bordered table-hover"}, 
            React.DOM.thead(null, 
                React.DOM.tr(null, 
                    React.DOM.th(null, "Public APIs affected"), React.DOM.th(null, "Path Weight")
                ), 
                
                  apis.length === 0 ?
                    React.DOM.tr(null, React.DOM.td({className: "info-row"}, "No affected APIs found"))
                  : apiRows
                
            )
          )
        )
      )
    );
  }

});
```

The browser says that the snippet that I am getting the error in the React JS library code is the following(to be precise, I am getting the error in the variable node(last variable) inside this snippet)

```js
function createNodesFromMarkup(markup, handleScript) {
  var node = dummyNode;
  ("production" !== "development" ? invariant(!!dummyNode, 'createNodesFromMarkup dummy not initialized') : invariant(!!dummyNode));
  var nodeName = getNodeName(markup);

  var wrap = nodeName && getMarkupWrap(nodeName);
  if (wrap) {
    node.innerHTML = wrap[1] + markup + wrap[2];

    var wrapDepth = wrap[0];
    while (wrapDepth--) {
      node = node.lastChild;
    }
  } else {
    node.innerHTML = markup;
  }

  var scripts = node.getElementsByTagName('script');
  if (scripts.length) {
    ("production" !== "development" ? invariant(
      handleScript,
      'createNodesFromMarkup(...): Unexpected <script> element rendered.'
    ) : invariant(handleScript));
    createArrayFrom(scripts).forEach(handleScript);
  }

  var nodes = createArrayFrom(node.childNodes);
  while (node.lastChild) {
    node.removeChild(node.lastChild);
  }
  return nodes;
}
```

Any help would be appreciated.
Thanks.

Comment: use pagination to display fewer records at once to the user; you simply have too much to show on one page.

Comment: How do i do pagination in this?

Comment: Pagination needs to happen to the data before you pass it to your react component; you can also easily add a pagination control from some of the OS that already exists: https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-pager

There are also solutions out there that use a row buffer technique, where essentially it acts like everything is rendered but the row doesn't get rendered until scroll: https://facebook.github.io/fixed-data-table/